# (de)Serialization of a custom type

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I'm using XNA/C# and I'm trying to load my level datas from an XML file.

I'm using the `XmlSerializer` class for that, but I can't deserialize a Vector3.

Here's how I would see `Vector3(5.3, 4.5, 1.2)` (de)serialized:

```
<Vector3>5.3, 4.5, 1.2</Vector3>
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I would use LINQ to XML

Comment: Is storage size important to you?  For Vector3's in a game, I would assume you could have a great number of these.  XML might be very very large for you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no option to customize serialization of an external class. For your custom classes you can implement IXmlSerializable (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). See also: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/474453/How-to-customize-XML-serialization

You could write your custom XmlVector3 with some conversion operator: (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx).